# Firebase PHP-JWT with Zend 2.0 cannot load module

Tags: php, zend-framework2, jwt

I installed php-jwt from https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt with composer.

I now have the library located in vendor\firebase\php-jwt\Firebase\PHP-JWT and the content of this directory is the same as on git.

in application.config.php i have:

```
'modules' => array(
   // 'ZendDeveloperTools',
    'DoctrineModule',
    'DoctrineORMModule',        
    'JWT'
),
```

in autoload_namespaces.php i have:

```
'JWT\\' => array($vendorDir . '/firebase/php-jwt/Firebase'),
```

autoload_classmap.php :

```
'JWT' => $vendorDir . '/firebase/php-jwt/Firebase/PHP-JWT/Authentication/JWT.php',
```

Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Module (JWT) could not be initialized.' in \vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager.php on line 175
```

I don't know what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The php-jwt lib is not a ZF2 module, so you cannot load it as a zf2 module. Simply use the JWT lib in your module (e.g. Application module from ZF2 skeleton app)

Comment: Yea that worked for me, i've already done it, thanks for the answer. I am new to zend and was tricky because composer installed it along with other modules.

Answer (score 3):

We can use JWT directly from the AuthController Like:

At the Top:

```
use Firebase\JWT\JWT;
```

Then create a function to generate JWT token like:

```
public function generateAuthToken($userData, $data) {
        if(password_verify($data['password'], $userData['hashPassword'])) {
            $tokenId    = base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(32));
            $issuedAt   = time();

            $data = [
                'iat'  => $issuedAt,         // Issued at: time when the token was generated
                'jti'  => $tokenId,          // Json Token Id: an unique identifier for the token
                'data'  => $userData
            ];

            $jwt = JWT::encode($data, 'testKey', self::JWT_ALGO); //use self::JWT_ALGO => HS512
            $unencodedArray = ['jwt' => $jwt];
            return json_encode($unencodedArray);
        }
    }
```

And use following function to check and decode token:

```
public function checkAuthToken($data) {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $authHeader = $request->getHeader('Authorization');

        if($authHeader) {
            list($token) = sscanf( $authHeader->toString(), 'Authorization: Bearer %s');
            if($token) {
                try{
                    $secretKey = 'testKey';
                    $decryptedToken = JWT::decode($token, $secretKey, [self::JWT_ALGO]); // //use self::JWT_ALGO => HS512
                    return $decryptedToken->data;
                } catch (\Exception $ex) {
                    return false;
                }                
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```